# CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in Nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, request, http-post

There is a php script:

```
$host = API_HOST."/getawb";
$username = USERNAME;

$curl_parameters['order_ids'] = array();

$curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $host,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($curl_parameters),
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => 1.0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false
  );

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_options);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

I try to connect to server with Nodejs, but I can not post data with http request.
I always got a following error:

*"Login statusCode: 200


**Warning**:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in **/www/wwwroot/ldtapi.plgfutar.hu/dashboard.php** on line **316**



**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/www/wwwroot/ldtapi.plgfutar.hu/dashboard.php** on line **321**

{"result":"success","event":"getawb","msg":[]}"*

My code is the following:

```
function getAwb() {         
  
  const url = `${protocol}//${host}${getawbpath}`

  const data = JSON.stringify({
    order_ids: '97621'
  });

  const options = {              
    mehod: 'POST',                                             
    auth: username,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: data
  };

  const req = http.request(url, options, (res) => {               
    console.log('Login statusCode:', res.statusCode);
          
    res.on('data', (d) => {                       
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });

    res.on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });                                           

  req.write(data);

  req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
  });

  req.end();

getAwb();
```

What's wrong with my code? How should I post the data to server to get a required response?

Comment: What does curl have to do with these errors? They are quite specific about what's wrong with the PHP code, they even give you a line number to look at. As for the JS, why do you think that `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is a valid property name for this method's parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Problems i see:

- how do you ended mixing PHP and nodejs options ?
  (CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is a php options)
  you need to read the documentation to find proper options.
  (see exemple below)
- http_build_query returns a querystring. In your nodejs exemple you send a json payload to the server which is not the same. you need to generate a query string if thats is what the server expects.

```
// query string generation in php
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
);
echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
// foo=bar&baz=boom
```

```
$curl_parameters['order_ids'] = array(12);
http_build_query($curl_parameters);
// shows : order_ids%5B0%5D=12
```

from here i get this sample code which should work (https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs)
some more here : https://usefulangle.com/post/167/nodejs-post-request

```
const https = require('https')

const data = 'order_ids%5B0%5D=12'

const options = {
  hostname: host,
  auth: username
  port: 443,
  path: getawbpath,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I try your suggestion but till get the same error code.

Comment: shall i see the relevant line of php : /www/wwwroot/ldtapi.plgfutar.hu/dashboard.php on line 316

Comment: Sure but how to save out? My js file contains 140 lines.
Meanwhile maybe I figured out the issue but still not able to solve it. So, the PHP example request an array and after that it is converted with http_build_query.  How can I solve it in node? Now I know the array looks like different in JS, bascially PHP array looks like and object in JS. But the server is still not able to understand the sent object.

Comment: i edited my answer. looks like you dont push the right data. its not { order_ids: '97621' } like in your nodejs code. it is { order_ids: ['97621'] } AND querystringified : order_ids[0]=97621

Comment: I tried to send all of the variant but still failed.'order_ids[0]=97621' and  'order_ids%5B0%5D=97621' and { order_ids: ['97621'] } and ['order_ids[0]=97621']. In case of the last two variants I got a new error id as "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE". Any further idea how to fix it?

Comment: One more info. I am also not sure about how the php array should looks like. arrray (1,2,3) or array (order_id => 1, order_id => 2, order_id => 3). There is no info about it in the API doc.

Comment: if your php script works then this code is to be converted to nodejs : $curl_parameters['order_ids'] = array(); http_build_query($curl_parameters)

Comment: then many ids would be written : $curl_parameters['order_ids'] = array(1, 2, 3);

Comment: ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE makes sens as nodejs expect a string not an array

Comment: I run out of ideas. I also tried to parse the data and httpBuildQuery npm function but nothing is working. And also the above ideas. Also tried to google how to post array but didn't find anything. I think the main question is how to post array with nodejs?